# Error creating Expression in Biztalk 2010, Assembly reference error?

Tags: biztalk, biztalk-2010

I am adding an Expression in Biztalk 2010, which is as follows;

`msgSalesOrder_Complete=msgSalesOrder;`

`msgSalesOrder_Complete.Comment="Work Done";`

But i am getting the Assembly Rerference missing error for `msgSalesOrder_Complete.Comment`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How is msgSalesOrder_Complete defined?

If it's a message schema, then Comment must be a (properly) distinguished or promoted property. If it's a .NET class, then the Comment member must be visible to the BizTalk project.

Obviously, the BizTalk project must have a reference to the project where the type of msgSalesOrder_Complete is defined, but I'm assuming this is the case...

Comment: msgSalesOrder_Complete is a Message schema and yes its a promoted property and i have also have added the refernce.

Comment: If it's a promoted property, as opposed to a distinguished property, then you have to access it like this: `msgSalesOrder_Complete(NS.Comment) = "Work done"` where NS is the full .NET namespace of the property schema.